# cross-compiled Valgrind does not detect obvious leaks

Tags: x86, valgrind, openwrt, uclibc

I cross compiled Valgrind to openwrt x86 platform. It doesn't detect any leaks when running on target. On Ubuntu, it works fine.

My test program is simple

```
main()
{
   char *p = malloc(10000);

   *(p-1) = 1;
}
```

Relevant compilation steps

```
i486-openwrt-linux-uclibc-gcc -c -o leak.o -pipe -march=i486 -fhonour-copts  -I/home/r2/external/openwrt/staging_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.30.1/usr/include -I/home/r2/external/openwrt/staging_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.30.1/include -I/home/r2/external/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-i386_gcc-4.1.2_uClibc-0.9.30.1/include  -O0 -g -I. -Idbus -I/home/r2/external/openwrt/staging_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.30.1/usr/include leak.c
leak.c: In function 'main':
leak.c:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'malloc'
  CC  leak.c
i486-openwrt-linux-uclibc-gcc leak.o  -L/hom e/r2/external/openwrt/staging_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.30.1/usr/lib -L/home/r2/external/openwrt/staging_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.30.1/lib -L/home/r2/external/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-i386_gcc-4.1.2_uClibc-0.9.30.1/lib  -o leak
  LD  leak
```

It's not statically linked. objdump confirms that

```
objdump -x build_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.30.1/test/leak  

build_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.30.1/test/leak:     file format elf32-i386
build_dir/target-i386_uClibc-0.9.30.1/test/leak
architecture: i386, flags 0x00000112:
EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS, D_PAGED
start address 0x08048340

Program Header:
    PHDR off    0x00000034 vaddr 0x08048034 paddr 0x08048034 align 2**2
         filesz 0x000000c0 memsz 0x000000c0 flags r-x
  INTERP off    0x000000f4 vaddr 0x080480f4 paddr 0x080480f4 align 2**0
         filesz 0x00000014 memsz 0x00000014 flags r--
    LOAD off    0x00000000 vaddr 0x08048000 paddr 0x08048000 align 2**12
         filesz 0x000004ac memsz 0x000004ac flags r-x
    LOAD off    0x000004ac vaddr 0x080494ac paddr 0x080494ac align 2**12
         filesz 0x000000f4 memsz 0x00000110 flags rw-
 DYNAMIC off    0x000004c0 vaddr 0x080494c0 paddr 0x080494c0 align 2**2
         filesz 0x000000b8 memsz 0x000000b8 flags rw-
   STACK off    0x00000000 vaddr 0x00000000 paddr 0x00000000 align 2**2
         filesz 0x00000000 memsz 0x00000000 flags rw-

Dynamic Section:
  NEEDED               libgcc_s.so.1
  NEEDED               libc.so.0
  INIT                 0x080482d4
  FINI                 0x08048490
  HASH                 0x08048108
  STRTAB               0x080481e4
  SYMTAB               0x08048144
  STRSZ                0x0000009c
  SYMENT               0x00000010
  DEBUG                0x00000000
  PLTGOT               0x08049578
  PLTRELSZ             0x00000020
  PLTREL               0x00000011
  JMPREL               0x080482b4
  VERNEED              0x08048294
  VERNEEDNUM           0x00000001
  VERSYM               0x08048280

Version References:
  required from libgcc_s.so.1:
    0x0b792650 0x00 02 GCC_3.0

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .interp       00000014  080480f4  080480f4  000000f4  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  1 .hash         0000003c  08048108  08048108  00000108  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  2 .dynsym       000000a0  08048144  08048144  00000144  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  3 .dynstr       0000009c  080481e4  080481e4  000001e4  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  4 .gnu.version  00000014  08048280  08048280  00000280  2**1
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  5 .gnu.version_r 00000020  08048294  08048294  00000294  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  6 .rel.plt      00000020  080482b4  080482b4  000002b4  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  7 .init         0000001c  080482d4  080482d4  000002d4  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  8 .plt          00000050  080482f0  080482f0  000002f0  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  9 .text         00000150  08048340  08048340  00000340  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 10 .fini         00000017  08048490  08048490  00000490  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 11 .eh_frame     00000004  080484a8  080484a8  000004a8  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 12 .ctors        00000008  080494ac  080494ac  000004ac  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 13 .dtors        00000008  080494b4  080494b4  000004b4  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 14 .jcr          00000004  080494bc  080494bc  000004bc  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 15 .dynamic      000000b8  080494c0  080494c0  000004c0  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 16 .got.plt      0000001c  08049578  08049578  00000578  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 17 .data         0000000c  08049594  08049594  00000594  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 18 .bss          0000001c  080495a0  080495a0  000005a0  2**2
                  ALLOC
 19 .comment      00000036  00000000  00000000  000005a0  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
 20 .debug_aranges 00000020  00000000  00000000  000005d6  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 21 .debug_pubnames 0000001b  00000000  00000000  000005f6  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 22 .debug_info   000000b1  00000000  00000000  00000611  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 23 .debug_abbrev 0000004e  00000000  00000000  000006c2  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 24 .debug_line   00000039  00000000  00000000  00000710  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 25 .debug_frame  00000058  00000000  00000000  0000074c  2**2
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 26 .debug_loc    00000043  00000000  00000000  000007a4  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
SYMBOL TABLE:
080480f4 l    d  .interp    00000000              .interp
08048108 l    d  .hash  00000000              .hash
08048144 l    d  .dynsym    00000000              .dynsym
080481e4 l    d  .dynstr    00000000              .dynstr
08048280 l    d  .gnu.version   00000000              .gnu.version
08048294 l    d  .gnu.version_r 00000000              .gnu.version_r
080482b4 l    d  .rel.plt   00000000              .rel.plt
080482d4 l    d  .init  00000000              .init
080482f0 l    d  .plt   00000000              .plt
08048340 l    d  .text  00000000              .text
08048490 l    d  .fini  00000000              .fini
080484a8 l    d  .eh_frame  00000000              .eh_frame
080494ac l    d  .ctors 00000000              .ctors
080494b4 l    d  .dtors 00000000              .dtors
080494bc l    d  .jcr   00000000              .jcr
080494c0 l    d  .dynamic   00000000              .dynamic
08049578 l    d  .got.plt   00000000              .got.plt
08049594 l    d  .data  00000000              .data
080495a0 l    d  .bss   00000000              .bss
00000000 l    d  .comment   00000000              .comment
00000000 l    d  .debug_aranges 00000000              .debug_aranges
00000000 l    d  .debug_pubnames    00000000              .debug_pubnames
00000000 l    d  .debug_info    00000000              .debug_info
00000000 l    d  .debug_abbrev  00000000              .debug_abbrev
00000000 l    d  .debug_line    00000000              .debug_line
00000000 l    d  .debug_frame   00000000              .debug_frame
00000000 l    d  .debug_loc 00000000              .debug_loc
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000              crtstuff.c
080494ac l     O .ctors 00000000              __CTOR_LIST__
080494b4 l     O .dtors 00000000              __DTOR_LIST__
080484a8 l     O .eh_frame  00000000              __EH_FRAME_BEGIN__
080494bc l     O .jcr   00000000              __JCR_LIST__
080495a0 l     O .bss   00000001              completed.2431
0804959c l     O .data  00000000              p.2429
08048370 l     F .text  00000000              __do_global_dtors_aux
080495a4 l     O .bss   00000018              object.2483
080483d0 l     F .text  00000000              frame_dummy
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000              crtstuff.c
080494b0 l     O .ctors 00000000              __CTOR_END__
080494b8 l     O .dtors 00000000              __DTOR_END__
080484a8 l     O .eh_frame  00000000              __FRAME_END__
080494bc l     O .jcr   00000000              __JCR_END__
08048460 l     F .text  00000000              __do_global_ctors_aux
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000              initfini.c
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000              leak.c
080494c0 l     O .dynamic   00000000              .hidden _DYNAMIC
08049598 l     O .data  00000000              .hidden __dso_handle
08049578 l     O .got.plt   00000000              .hidden _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
00000000       F *UND*  00000000              malloc
08048310  w    F *UND*  00000000              __deregister_frame_info_bases@@GCC_3.0
080482d4 g     F .init  00000000              _init
08048340 g     F .text  00000022              _start
00000000       F *UND*  00000000              __uClibc_main
080495a0 g       *ABS*  00000000              __bss_start
08048424 g     F .text  00000033              main
08048330  w    F *UND*  00000000              __register_frame_info_bases@@GCC_3.0
08049594  w      .data  00000000              data_start
08048490 g     F .fini  00000000              _fini
08048364 g     F .text  00000000              .hidden __get_pc_thunk_bx
080495a0 g       *ABS*  00000000              _edata
080495bc g       *ABS*  00000000              _end
08049594 g       .data  00000000              __data_start
00000000  w      *UND*  00000000              _Jv_RegisterClasses
```

Here is the valgrind output on the target x86 board

```
valgrind --leak-check=full -v -d -d -d -d  -d ./leak 
--5221:1:debuglog DebugLog system started by Stage 1, level 5 logging requested
--5221:1:launcher no tool requested, defaulting to 'memcheck'
--5221:2:launcher   selecting platform for './leak'
--5221:2:launcher   selecting platform for './leak'
--5221:2:launcher   opened './leak'
--5221:2:launcher   read 4096 bytes from './leak'
--5221:2:launcher   selected platform 'x86-linux'
--5221:1:launcher selected platform 'x86-linux'
--5221:1:launcher launching /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-x86-linux
--5221:1:debuglog DebugLog system started by Stage 2 (main), level 5 logging requested
--5221:1:main     Welcome to Valgrind version 3.8.0 debug logging
--5221:1:main     Checking current stack is plausible
--5221:1:main     Checking initial stack was noted
--5221:1:main     Starting the address space manager
--5221:2:aspacem            sp_at_startup = 0x00bfafb800 (supplied)
--5221:2:aspacem                  minAddr = 0x0004000000 (computed)
--5221:2:aspacem                  maxAddr = 0x00bfafafff (computed)
--5221:2:aspacem                   cStart = 0x0004000000 (computed)
--5221:2:aspacem                   vStart = 0x0061d7e000 (computed)
--5221:2:aspacem    suggested_clstack_top = 0x00beafbfff (computed)
--5221:2:aspacem    <<< SHOW_SEGMENTS: Initial layout (5 segments, 0 segnames)
--5221:2:aspacem      0: RSVN 0000000000-0003ffffff     64m ----- SmFixed
--5221:2:aspacem      1:      0004000000-0061d7dfff   1501m
--5221:2:aspacem      2: RSVN 0061d7e000-0061d7efff    4096 ----- SmFixed
--5221:2:aspacem      3:      0061d7f000-00bfafafff   1501m
--5221:2:aspacem      4: RSVN 00bfafb000-00ffffffff   1029m ----- SmFixed
--5221:2:aspacem    >>>
--5221:2:aspacem    Reading /proc/self/maps
--5221:2:aspacem    <<< SHOW_SEGMENTS: With contents of /proc/self/maps (12 segments, 1 segnames)
--5221:2:aspacem    ( 0) /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-x86-linux
--5221:2:aspacem      0: RSVN 0000000000-0003ffffff     64m ----- SmFixed
--5221:2:aspacem      1:      0004000000-0037ffffff    832m
--5221:2:aspacem      2: FILE 0038000000-0038288fff 2658304 r-x-- d=0x803 i=33422   o=4096    (0)
--5221:2:aspacem      3: FILE 0038289000-003828afff    8192 rw--- d=0x803 i=33422   o=2658304 (0)
--5221:2:aspacem      4: ANON 003828b000-0038d20fff     10m rw---
--5221:2:aspacem      5:      0038d21000-0061d7dfff    656m
--5221:2:aspacem      6: RSVN 0061d7e000-0061d7efff    4096 ----- SmFixed
--5221:2:aspacem      7:      0061d7f000-00bfae7fff   1501m
--5221:2:aspacem      8: ANON 00bfae8000-00bfafcfff   86016 rw---
--5221:2:aspacem      9: RSVN 00bfafd000-00ffffdfff   1029m ----- SmFixed
--5221:2:aspacem     10: ANON 00ffffe000-00ffffefff    4096 r-x--
--5221:2:aspacem     11: RSVN 00fffff000-00ffffffff    4096 ----- SmFixed
--5221:2:aspacem    >>>
--5221:1:main     Address space manager is running
--5221:1:main     Starting the dynamic memory manager
--5221:1:mallocfr newSuperblock at 0x61D7F000 (pszB 4194288)  owner VALGRIND/tool
--5221:1:mallocfr deferred_reclaimSuperblock at 0x61D7F000 (pszB 4194288)  (prev 0x0) owner VALGRIND/tool
--5221:1:main     Dynamic memory manager is running
--5221:1:main     Initialise m_debuginfo
--5221:1:main     VG_(libdir) = /usr/lib/valgrind
--5221:1:main     Getting launcher's name ...
--5221:1:main     ... /usr/bin/valgrind
--5221:1:main     Get hardware capabilities ...
--5221:1:main     ... arch = X86, hwcaps = x86-sse1-sse2
--5221:1:main     Getting the working directory at startup
--5221:1:main     ... /root
--5221:1:main     Split up command line
--5221:1:main     (early_) Process Valgrind's command line options
--5221:1:main     Create initial image
--5221:1:initimg  Loading client
--5221:1:initimg  Setup client env
--5221:2:initimg    preload_string:
--5221:2:initimg      "/usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-x86-linux.so:/usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so"
--5221:1:initimg  Setup client stack: size will be 16777216
--5221:2:initimg    Client info: initial_IP=0x40008B4 initial_TOC=0x0 brk_base=0x804A000
--5221:2:initimg    Client info: initial_SP=0xBEAFBD80 max_stack_size=16777216
--5221:1:initimg  Setup client data (brk) segment
--5221:1:main     Setup file descriptors
--5221:1:main     Create fake /proc/<pid>/cmdline
--5221:1:main     Initialise the tool part 1 (pre_clo_init)
--5221:1:mallocfr deferred_reclaimSuperblock NULL (prev 0x61D7F000) owner VALGRIND/tool
--5221:1:mallocfr newSuperblock at 0x6217F000 (pszB 1048560)  owner VALGRIND/exectxt
--5221:1:main     Print help and quit, if requested
--5221:1:main     (main_) Process Valgrind's command line options, setup logging
--5221:1:mallocfr newSuperblock at 0x6227F000 (pszB 1048560)  owner VALGRIND/core
--5221:1:main     Print the preamble...
==5221== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5221== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5221== Using Valgrind-3.8.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5221== Command: ./leak
==5221== 
--5221-- Valgrind options:
--5221--    --leak-check=full
--5221--    -v
--5221--    -d
--5221--    -d
--5221--    -d
--5221--    -d
--5221--    -d
--5221-- Contents of /proc/version:
--5221--   Linux version 2.6.32.27 (ramesh@r2) (gcc version 4.1.2) #16 Mon Apr 1 15:37:49 PDT 2013
--5221-- Arch and hwcaps: X86, x86-sse1-sse2
--5221-- Page sizes: currently 4096, max supported 4096
--5221-- Valgrind library directory: /usr/lib/valgrind
--5221:1:main     ...finished the preamble
--5221:1:main     Initialise the tool part 2 (post_clo_init)
--5221:1:main     Initialise TT/TC
--5221:2:transtab   cache: 8 sectors of 27597024 bytes each = 220776192 total
--5221:2:transtab   table: 524168 total entries, max occupancy 340704 (65%)
--5221:1:main     Initialise redirects
--5221:1:mallocfr newSuperblock at 0x623FA000 (pszB 1048560)  owner VALGRIND/dinfo
--5221:1:main     Load initial debug info
--5221-- Reading syms from /root/leak
--5221:1:redir    transfer ownership V -> C of 0x3803d000 .. 0x3803dfff
--5221:1:main     Initialise scheduler (phase 1)
--5221:1:sched    sched_init_phase1
--5221-- Scheduler: using generic scheduler lock implementation.
--5221:1:main     Tell tool about initial permissions
--5221:2:main       tell tool about 0004000000-0004003fff r-x
--5221:2:main       tell tool about 0004004000-0004005fff rw-
--5221:2:main       tell tool about 0008048000-0008048fff r-x
--5221:2:main       tell tool about 0008049000-0008049fff rw-
--5221:2:main       tell tool about 000804a000-000804afff rwx
--5221:2:main       tell tool about 003803d000-003803dfff r-x
--5221:2:main       tell tool about 00beafb000-00beafbfff rwx
--5221:2:main       mark stack inaccessible 00beafb000-00beafbd7f
--5221:1:main     Initialise scheduler (phase 2)
--5221:1:sched    sched_init_phase2: tid_main=1, cls_end=0xbeafbfff, cls_sz=16777216
--5221:1:main     Finalise initial image
--5221:1:main     Initialise signal management
--5221:1:main     Load suppressions
--5221-- Reading suppressions file: /usr/lib/valgrind/default.supp
--5221:2:stacks     register 0xBEAFB000-0xBEAFBFFF as stack 0
--5221:1:main     
--5221:1:main     
--5221:1:aspacem  <<< SHOW_SEGMENTS: Memory layout at client startup (25 segments, 3 segnames)
--5221:1:aspacem  ( 0) /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-x86-linux
--5221:1:aspacem  ( 1) /root/leak
--5221:1:aspacem  ( 2) /lib/ld-uClibc-0.9.30.1.so
--5221:1:aspacem    0: RSVN 0000000000-0003ffffff     64m ----- SmFixed
--5221:1:aspacem    1: file 0004000000-0004003fff   16384 r-x-- d=0x803 i=86      o=0       (2)
--5221:1:aspacem    2: file 0004004000-0004005fff    8192 rw--- d=0x803 i=86      o=12288   (2)
--5221:1:aspacem    3:      0004006000-0008047fff     64m
--5221:1:aspacem    4: file 0008048000-0008048fff    4096 r-x-- d=0x803 i=33471   o=0       (1)
--5221:1:aspacem    5: file 0008049000-0008049fff    4096 rw--- d=0x803 i=33471   o=0       (1)
--5221:1:aspacem    6: anon 000804a000-000804afff    4096 rwx--
--5221:1:aspacem    7: RSVN 000804b000-0008849fff 8384512 ----- SmLower
--5221:1:aspacem    8:      000884a000-0037ffffff    759m
--5221:1:aspacem    9: FILE 0038000000-003803cfff  249856 r-x-- d=0x803 i=33422   o=4096    (0)
--5221:1:aspacem   10: file 003803d000-003803dfff    4096 r-x-- d=0x803 i=33422   o=253952  (0)
--5221:1:aspacem   11: FILE 003803e000-0038288fff 2404352 r-x-- d=0x803 i=33422   o=258048  (0)
--5221:1:aspacem   12: FILE 0038289000-003828afff    8192 rw--- d=0x803 i=33422   o=2658304 (0)
--5221:1:aspacem   13: ANON 003828b000-0038d20fff     10m rw---
--5221:1:aspacem   14:      0038d21000-0061d7dfff    656m
--5221:1:aspacem   15: RSVN 0061d7e000-0061d7efff    4096 ----- SmFixed
--5221:1:aspacem   16: ANON 0061d7f000-0062509fff 7909376 rwx--
--5221:1:aspacem   17:      006250a000-00bdafbfff   1461m
--5221:1:aspacem   18: RSVN 00bdafc000-00beafafff     15m ----- SmUpper
--5221:1:aspacem   19: anon 00beafb000-00beafbfff    4096 rwx--
--5221:1:aspacem   20:      00beafc000-00bfae7fff     15m
--5221:1:aspacem   21: ANON 00bfae8000-00bfafcfff   86016 rw---
--5221:1:aspacem   22: RSVN 00bfafd000-00ffffdfff   1029m ----- SmFixed
--5221:1:aspacem   23: ANON 00ffffe000-00ffffefff    4096 r-x--
--5221:1:aspacem   24: RSVN 00fffff000-00ffffffff    4096 ----- SmFixed
--5221:1:aspacem  >>>
--5221:1:main     
--5221:1:main     
--5221:1:main     Running thread 1
--5221:1:syswrap- entering VG_(main_thread_wrapper_NORETURN)
--5221:1:aspacem  allocated thread stack at 0x6250a000 size 1064960
--5221:1:syswrap- run_a_thread_NORETURN(tid=1): pre-thread_wrapper
--5221:1:syswrap- thread_wrapper(tid=1): entry
--5221:1:gdbsrv   entering call_gdbserver init_reason ... pid 5221 tid 1 status VgTs_Runnable sched_jmpbuf_valid 0
--5221:1:gdbsrv   gdbserver_init gdbserver embedded in valgrind: gdbserver protocol box extracted from gdb 6.6
==5221== embedded gdbserver: reading from /tmp/vgdb-pipe-from-vgdb-to-5221-by-root-on-???
==5221== embedded gdbserver: writing to   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-5221-by-root-on-???
==5221== embedded gdbserver: shared mem   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-5221-by-root-on-???
==5221== 
==5221== TO CONTROL THIS PROCESS USING vgdb (which you probably
==5221== don't want to do, unless you know exactly what you're doing,
==5221== or are doing some strange experiment):
==5221==   /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=5221 ...command...
==5221== 
==5221== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
==5221==   /path/to/gdb ./leak
==5221== and then give GDB the following command
==5221==   target remote | /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=5221
==5221== --pid is optional if only one valgrind process is running
==5221== 
--5221:1:gdbsrv   Opening read side /tmp/vgdb-pipe-from-vgdb-to-5221-by-root-on-???
--5221:1:gdbsrv   result fd 3
--5221:1:gdbsrv   result safe_fd 1019
--5221:1:transtab allocate sector 0
--5221:1:mallocfr newSuperblock at 0x64AE1000 (pszB   65520)  owner VALGRIND/ttaux
--5221:1:mallocfr newSuperblock at 0x64AF1000 (pszB   65520)  owner VALGRIND/errors
--5221:1:signals  extending a stack base 0xbeafb000 down by 4096
--5221:2:stacks     change stack 0 from 0xBEAFB000-0xBEAFBFFF to 0xBEAFA000-0xBEAFBFFF
--5221:1:syswrap- thread_wrapper(tid=1): exit
--5221:1:syswrap- run_a_thread_NORETURN(tid=1): post-thread_wrapper
--5221:1:syswrap- run_a_thread_NORETURN(tid=1): last one standing
--5221:1:main     entering VG_(shutdown_actions_NORETURN)
--5221:1:aspacem  <<< SHOW_SEGMENTS: Memory layout at client shutdown (43 segments, 8 segnames)
--5221:1:aspacem  ( 0) /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-x86-linux
--5221:1:aspacem  ( 1) /root/leak
--5221:1:aspacem  ( 2) /lib/ld-uClibc-0.9.30.1.so
--5221:1:aspacem  ( 3) /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-5221-by-root-on-???
--5221:1:aspacem  ( 4) /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-x86-linux.so
--5221:1:aspacem  ( 5) /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so
--5221:1:aspacem  ( 6) /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
--5221:1:aspacem  ( 7) /lib/libuClibc-0.9.30.1.so
--5221:1:aspacem    0: RSVN 0000000000-0003ffffff     64m ----- SmFixed
--5221:1:aspacem    1: file 0004000000-0004003fff   16384 r-xT- d=0x803 i=86      o=0       (2)
--5221:1:aspacem    2: file 0004004000-0004004fff    4096 r---- d=0x803 i=86      o=12288   (2)
--5221:1:aspacem    3: file 0004005000-0004005fff    4096 rw--- d=0x803 i=86      o=16384   (2)
--5221:1:aspacem    4: anon 0004006000-0004006fff    4096 rw---
--5221:1:aspacem    5:      0004007000-0004007fff    4096
--5221:1:aspacem    6: file 0004008000-0004008fff    4096 r-xT- d=0x803 i=33412   o=0       (4)
--5221:1:aspacem    7: file 0004009000-0004009fff    4096 rw--- d=0x803 i=33412   o=0       (4)
--5221:1:aspacem    8: file 000400a000-0004012fff   36864 r-xT- d=0x803 i=33423   o=0       (5)
--5221:1:aspacem    9: file 0004013000-0004013fff    4096 rw--- d=0x803 i=33423   o=32768   (5)
--5221:1:aspacem   10: file 0004014000-000401dfff   40960 r-xT- d=0x803 i=338     o=0       (6)
--5221:1:aspacem   11: file 000401e000-000401efff    4096 rw--- d=0x803 i=338     o=36864   (6)
--5221:1:aspacem   12: file 000401f000-0004064fff  286720 r-xT- d=0x803 i=135     o=0       (7)
--5221:1:aspacem   13: file 0004065000-0004065fff    4096 r---- d=0x803 i=135     o=282624  (7)
--5221:1:aspacem   14: file 0004066000-0004066fff    4096 rw--- d=0x803 i=135     o=286720  (7)
--5221:1:aspacem   15: anon 0004067000-000406bfff   20480 rw---
--5221:1:aspacem   16:      000406c000-0008047fff     63m
--5221:1:aspacem   17: file 0008048000-0008048fff    4096 r-xT- d=0x803 i=33471   o=0       (1)
--5221:1:aspacem   18: file 0008049000-0008049fff    4096 rw--- d=0x803 i=33471   o=0       (1)
--5221:1:aspacem   19: anon 000804a000-000804cfff   12288 rwx--
--5221:1:aspacem   20: RSVN 000804d000-0008849fff 8376320 ----- SmLower
--5221:1:aspacem   21:      000884a000-0037ffffff    759m
--5221:1:aspacem   22: FILE 0038000000-003803cfff  249856 r-x-- d=0x803 i=33422   o=4096    (0)
--5221:1:aspacem   23: file 003803d000-003803dfff    4096 r-x-- d=0x803 i=33422   o=253952  (0)
--5221:1:aspacem   24: FILE 003803e000-0038288fff 2404352 r-x-- d=0x803 i=33422   o=258048  (0)
--5221:1:aspacem   25: FILE 0038289000-003828afff    8192 rw--- d=0x803 i=33422   o=2658304 (0)
--5221:1:aspacem   26: ANON 003828b000-0038d20fff     10m rw---
--5221:1:aspacem   27:      0038d21000-0061d7dfff    656m
--5221:1:aspacem   28: RSVN 0061d7e000-0061d7efff    4096 ----- SmFixed
--5221:1:aspacem   29: ANON 0061d7f000-0062509fff 7909376 rwx--
--5221:1:aspacem   30: ANON 006250a000-006250bfff    8192 -----
--5221:1:aspacem   31: ANON 006250c000-006260bfff 1048576 rwx--
--5221:1:aspacem   32: ANON 006260c000-006260dfff    8192 -----
--5221:1:aspacem   33: FILE 006260e000-006260efff    4096 rw--- d=0x00b i=8236    o=0       (3)
--5221:1:aspacem   34: ANON 006260f000-0064b08fff     36m rwx--
--5221:1:aspacem   35:      0064b09000-00bdafbfff   1423m
--5221:1:aspacem   36: RSVN 00bdafc000-00beaf9fff     15m ----- SmUpper
--5221:1:aspacem   37: anon 00beafa000-00beafbfff    8192 rwx--
--5221:1:aspacem   38:      00beafc000-00bfae7fff     15m
--5221:1:aspacem   39: ANON 00bfae8000-00bfafcfff   86016 rw---
--5221:1:aspacem   40: RSVN 00bfafd000-00ffffdfff   1029m ----- SmFixed
--5221:1:aspacem   41: ANON 00ffffe000-00ffffefff    4096 r-x--
--5221:1:aspacem   42: RSVN 00fffff000-00ffffffff    4096 ----- SmFixed
--5221:1:aspacem  >>>
==5221== 
==5221== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5221==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5221==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==5221== 
==5221== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5221== 
==5221== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
--5221-- 
--5221-- used_suppression:      1 ld(Cond)
==5221== 
==5221== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
--5221:1:gdbsrv   remote_finish (reason orderly_finish) 1019 -1
--5221:1:gdbsrv   unlinking
    /tmp/vgdb-pipe-from-vgdb-to-5221-by-root-on-???
    /tmp/vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-5221-by-root-on-???
    /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-5221-by-root-on-???
--5221:1:core_os  VG_(terminate_NORETURN)(tid=1)
```

Answer (score 7):

It turns out that openwrt strips all libraries including valgrind's vgpreload_xxxxxx.so libs and libc.so. However, valgrind needs section headers and symbols in the .so files. I disabled stripping for libc and valgrind packages, then everything is working like charm. It took some digging into valgrind code to understand what is really going on. I wish there were some WARNINGs or errors from valgrind if it can't find any symbols to REDIR. Would have saved me 3 days. Oh well, learnt something new anyways.

Comment: A newer post referred me to this. This is all described in README_PACKAGERS in the Valgrind distribution.