# valgrind can not detect any leak

Tags: c, valgrind

We run our program on a Linux virtual machine which compiles from linux-2.6.3-long-term. I want to run `valgrind` on that machine, and I compile from source code in the suggested way.

```
./configure --prefix=/tmp/valgrind/
make
make install
```

Then, I copy the `/tmp/valgrind` to my own Linux machine, I put it on the directory `/data`, set the environment variables:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/data/valgrind/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/lib:/lib64:/data/valgrind/lib
export VALGRIND_LIB=/data/valgrind/lib/valgrind
```

The `valgrind` can work, and can detect some other errors except memory leak. Here is the result of running `valgrind ls -l`

```
==2207==
==2207== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2207==    at 0x80F3CDE: ??? (in /bin/busybox)
==2207==    by 0x80548ED: ??? (in /bin/busybox)
==2207==
==2207== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==2207==    at 0x80D8F77: ??? (in /bin/busybox)
==2207==    by 0x8048866: ??? (in /bin/busybox)
==2207==
==2207== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2207==    at 0x80F0F55: ??? (in /bin/busybox)
==2207==    by 0x80D8F49: ??? (in /bin/busybox)
==2207==    by 0x8048866: ??? (in /bin/busybox)
==2207==
==2207== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2207==    at 0x80F1000: ??? (in /bin/busybox)
==2207==    by 0x80D8F49: ??? (in /bin/busybox)
==2207==    by 0x8048866: ??? (in /bin/busybox)
==2207==
==2207==
==2207== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2207==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2207==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==2207==
==2207== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2207==
==2207== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2207== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==2207== ERROR SUMMARY: 2390 errors from 117 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The total heap usage is all zero. And I find someone has already meet the same problem:
[cross-compiled Valgrind does not detect obvious leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840091/cross-compiled-valgrind-does-not-detect-obvious-leaks)
Is it a known issue? 
The link above did not tell how to fix it, anyone know?

Comment: Are you sure you _have_ leaks?

Comment: Yes, It have definitely lost. I run the same command on my ubuntu, it can report definitely lost , memoery malloc and free.

Comment: Which version of Linux are you running on, compared with which version are you building on.  What `valgrind` does requires it to be incredibly 'intimate' with the o/s and libraries on which it is running; I'm not sure how much difference it will tolerate.  For example, `valgrind` 3.8.1 compiled and ran usefully on Mac OS X 10.7.x, but fails to be useful when run on Mac OS X 10.8.x, even when compiled on 10.8.x.  Enough changed that it no longer works (which is a confounded nuisance, it must be said).  Is there really a good reason not to compile `valgrind` on the machine where you'll run it?

Comment: Thank you for your hint, I will try to using another version linux to compile it. Because my own linux does not have compile environment, I can not compile the valgrind on my target OS.

Comment: I have tried to use the same version of linux kernel to build the valgrind, it still can not work. It is too sad.:(